# is there a way of adding a variable inside set.formula to use in a for loop

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

[Here is a link to a sample sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gvzoEpNV_HGLRyPt5rgHOTHNv6aF-I79qjpY9O7m_xc/edit?usp=sharing)

I have a sheet that has high medium and low as responses. I need to change these to numbers, so that I can create a chart, so I'm using the switch function. However the data is dynamic, so it depends on a couple of factors as to how much data there is.. I can get set.formula to update from the first data set but only through using cell references. Can I use dynamic variables inside a formula, so that if there are 5 data sets it will copy the formula 5x but change the row reference

I've tried changing it to set value, I've also tried adding in a variable + copyCell+

```
function weeklyReview()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Workzone Planning');
  var sessionSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Daily Plan');
  var calcSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Calc Sheet');
  var chartSheet = ss.getSheetByName('WeeklyReviewCalcs');
  var lastCol = sessionSheet.getLastColumn();
  var numDays = sheet.getRange('f11').getValue();
  var numSessions = sheet.getRange('c29').getValue();
  var startFormula = chartSheet.getRange('c4').activate();


for (var a=0; a<numDays; a++)
{  
  var day = calcSheet.getRange(a+3, 1).getValue()


  chartSheet.getRange('a1').setValue(day)
  chartSheet.getActiveCell().setFormula ('=SWITCH(\'Daily 
Plan\'!C15,"High", 2, "Medium", 1, "Low", 0, 0)');
  chartSheet.getActiveCell().offset(1, 0).setFormula('=SWITCH(\'Daily Plan\'!C14, "High", 2, "Medium", 1, "Low", 0, 0)');
  chartSheet.getActiveCell().offset(2, 0).setFormula('=SWITCH(\'Daily Plan\'!C19, "Yes", 1, "Half", -1, "No", -1, 0)');
  chartSheet.getActiveCell().offset(3, 0).setFormula('=SWITCH(\'Daily Plan\'!C16, "High", 2, "Medium", 1, "Low", 0, 0)');
  chartSheet.getActiveCell().offset(4, 0).setFormula('=SWITCH(\'Daily Plan\'!C17, "None", 2, "Some", 1, "Lots", 0, 0)');
  chartSheet.getActiveCell().offset(5, 0).setFormula('=SWITCH(\'Daily Plan\'!C18, 100%, 2, 66%, 1, 33%, 0, 0)');
    }
}
```

I want it to go to row 15 of the daily Plan sheet for the first iteration, then move down and go to row 38 etc... for the number of days that are being worked.

Comment: It would be easier to understand your request if you could provide a sample spreadsheet  where your different data ranges in Plan sheet are visible

Comment: link to sheet added to question

Comment: You need to give me permission

Comment: I've updated the link.. so it shouldn't need permissions..sorry

Comment: I see, the code below will work for you (for column C instead of A) if the empty contents do not contain dashes. If it is not possible for you to remove the dashes, you will have to manually iterate through the cells in column C until you encounter a dash (end of the data range)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Two points to help you solve the problem:

1. Use [getNextDataCell(direction)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnextdatacelldirection)
   It returns you the last contents containing cell of a continuous data range.

**Sample:**

```
var lastCell=sessionSheet.getRange("C14").getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN);
Logger.log(lastCell.getA1Notation());
```

> If the the value of `lastCell` is e.g. `C19` you know that your first
>   data range goes from row 14 to row 19.

2. Implement a counter variable within your formula statement.

**Sample:**

```
var firstRow=14;
var rowNumber=lastCell.getRow()-firstRow;
for(var i=0; i<rowNumber.length;i++){
  var row=i+14;
  chartSheet.getActiveCell().offset(i, 0).setFormula('=SWITCH(\'Daily Plan\'!C'+row+', "High", 2, "Medium", 1, "Low", 0, 0)');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks so much... This didn't actually work exactly how I needed it to, but it did give me the way to resolve my query... using the +row+ variable inside the formula.. :)